# Nginx keeps redirecting and adding tailing slashes

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect an app to some static html files.
I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy, and alias to use a specific path.

So I am using a simple Redirect within a react container:

```
redirectTo="/documentation/index-docs.html"
```

This is the Nginx config part used for that:

```
location /documentation {
  alias /workspace/documentation;
  rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
```

The current behavior is that it keeps looping and adding tailing slashes.

**http://localhost:3001/documentation/index-docs.html/////////////**

Did anyone encounter the same issue before ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this rule. However I didn't see any errors explaining described behavior except it will strip only the last trailing slash from the URI (use regex pattern with non-greedy quantifier `^(.+?)/+` to strip all of them). HTTP 301 permanent redirects are often cached by the browsers, did you try to clear your browser cache or open your URL from the incognito window?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for the clarifications.
I tried just exactly your quantifier, from the incognito window, it looping.

Comment: Sounds weird. Sorry, I don't know why it could happen.